# How to integrate dailymotion javascript sdk in phonegap application

Tags: cordova

I am a newbie to phonegap and daily motion javascript API. I need to integrate the javascript API in the existing phonegap project so that I will be able to upload the videos to daily motion and according the user will be able to see those videos.
I have downloaded the dailymotion sdk from [GitHub](https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-js). But from here onward I don't know how to move forward.

Thanks in advance.